# How can I get "go tool cover -html" to work with code in a monorepo?

Tags: go, code-coverage

Go 1.14.3

I have a coverage file that looks like this (trimmed for brevity):

```
mode: atomic
fooco/barproj/api/dao/dataSharingService/api.go:23.128,25.2 1 7
fooco/barproj/api/dao/highlights/highlights_dao.go:20.13,22.2 1 1
fooco/barproj/api/dao/testresult/testresult_dao.go:149.11,152.51 3 2
fooco/barproj/api/middleware/logging.go:19.44,20.72 1 4
```

The code is in a monorepo at `/Users/jcollum/work/barproj`. So `dataSharingService/api.go` is at: `src/api/dao/dataSharingService/api.go` and `highlights_dao.go` is at `src/api/dao/highlights/highlights_dao.go`.

Imports are like `"fooco/barproj/pkg/types"`.

My best attempt here was to add entries to GOPATH:

`GOPATH="/Users/jcollum/.go:/Users/jcollum/work/barproj/src/pkg/types:/Users/jcollum/work/barproj/src/pkg/dao" go tool cover -html="tests/coverage/api-coverage.out"`

But that failed:

```
cover: cannot find package "fooco/barproj/api/dao/dataSharingService" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14.3/libexec/src/fooco/barproj/api/dao/dataSharingService (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/justin.collum/.go/src/fooco/barproj/api/dao/dataSharingService (from $GOPATH)
    /Users/justin.collum/work/barproj/src/pkg/types/src/fooco/barproj/api/dao/dataSharingService
    /Users/justin.collum/work/barproj/src/pkg/dao/src/fooco/barproj/api/dao/dataSharingService
```

Coworker who is way ahead of me in the Go manual says this won't be possible without moving code around which sounds code smelly as heck.

**So is there any way to manipulate the GOPATH before calling `cover` to get it to see code that is in "non-standard" Go paths?** Or is there a better way to solve this than moving files around?

Some caveats:

- the [Go docs](https://golang.org/doc/gopath_code.html) discourage the use of symlinks for GOPATH but don't give a reason
- this is a team of 5+ people so asking people to move code around is a bit of a big ask
- reorganizing the repo is not an option I can consider
- GVM isn't an option, the team prefers not to use it

Comment: I ended up solving this by just copying files into my GOPATH but since that's not my ideal solution I'm gonna leave the question unanswered for now